# How to unify two Solr / Lucene indexes into one index without merging the inner segments together

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there a way to add the segments of one Solr core to another without a costly operation of merging the inner segments together?
For example if the first has 3 segments and the second 2, I want to create a unified core with 5 segments.

Comment: did you tried the MERGEINDEXES...?

Comment: I'm familiar with the command, but doesn't it merge the segments? @Abhijit Bashetti